# Access 2016 How can I use the value of a variable not the variable?

Tags: ms-access

Access 2016 VBA Code -

Lead in:
fullname is the table field name, tag is the property
msgbox fullname.tag
will show the value of tag

Problem:
Using the field name in a variable then trying to use the value of the variable
Example:
x = "fullname"
msgbox x.tag
does not show the contents of tag, error is: 424 object required
even if I Dim x as field or fields or variant I still can not get it to work.

How do I use the value of x, not x ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3):

You can't use a variable to reference a variable.

HOWEVER, you can most certainly use a string variable to referance a control on a form.

So,

```
dim strMyCtrl   as string
strMyCtrl = "LastName"

Now,
msgbox "value of LastName = " & me!LastName
msgbox "Value of LastName = " & me("LastName")
msgbox "Value of LastName = " & me("LastName").Value

or

msgbox "Value of LastName = " & me(strMyCtrl)
msgbox "Value of LastName = " & me(strMyCtrl).Value
```

And since you can referance the control with a string, then you can also grab the tag value also
eg:

```
msgbox "Value of LastName control tag value = " & me(strMyCtrl).tag.
```

So, if you have controls 1 to 5 named:
TextBox1
TextBox2
TextBox3
TextBox4
TextBox5

You  can grab the values like this:

```
dim i    as integer
dim strCtrl   as string

For i = 1 to 5
   strCtrl = "TextBox" & i
   msgbox "Value of " & strCtrl & " is = " & me(strCtrl)
Next i
```

So, no variable against a variable is allowed. However for controls, or even field names in a recordset, you can use a "string" variable with the name of the column, or as per above the name of the control.